# How do I echo custom article parameters in Joomla

Tags: php, xml, joomla, joomla1.5

I'm trying to create a simple text field that can be optionally shown on a Joomla article.
At the moment I have created 2x custom article params (viewable and quick_summary)

**administrator > components > com_content > models > article.xml**

```
<params group="advanced">
<param name="viewable" type="list" default="no" label="Viewable" description="">
<option value="no">No</option>
<option value="yes">yes</option>
</param>
<param name="quick_summary" type="textarea" rows="10" cols="30" 
    label="Summary" description="Summary" />
<param type="spacer" />
...
</params>
```

**In the template file**
To have the quick_summary show depending on the status of viewable I have used the following:

```
<?php 
if ($this->params->get('viewable') == "yes") {
echo $this->params->get('quick_summary');
}
?>
```

Any help hugely appreciated

Comment: FYI [This is where I got most of the above from](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1733986#p1733986)

Comment: so what exactly is your question? read the view and model files @ /components/com_article/  this should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USe

```
$htmlArray = $this->params->renderToArray('nameSpace','groupName');
```

This will return html of all parameters of groupName, as array. Then echo them using for loop or using index.

```
echo $this->params->render('nameSpace','groupName');
```

This will echo the html of all parameters of GroupName